# java input/ output file problems

Tags: java

the aim here with this method is to create a file if it does not exist but if it exists : open it and modify it...
but I get errors createNewFile() is not a member of the class, exist() is not a member of the class..i already imported java.io.*
now i post a snippet..i will hightlight the problems with comments for quicker help...

```
  public void writeCoordtoFile () throws IOException
  {
       File file = new File("FermiPresentCoord.txt");
     //  boolean yes = createNewFile("FermiPresentCoord.txt") throws IOException; i get error when i try to do this
       //boolean yes = exists("FermiPresentCoord.txt"); error exists is not a member of file 
       // creates the file
       file.createNewFile();

       // creates a FileWriter Object
       FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

       // Writes the content to the file
       writer.write(pos_Let);
       writer.write(pos_Num);
       writer.flush();
       writer.close();

  }
```

Comment: How r you compiling? Are you using Eclipse for this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to give the `file` object, as `createNewFile()` is a method of `File` class. Function's of that class can be accessed using the file's `object(file).methodName()`

```
File file = new File("FermiPresentCoord.txt");
boolean yes = file.createNewFile() 
boolean yes1 = file.exists();
```

Comment: this code won't compile as `file.exists` and `file.createNewFile` don't get parameters. use `file.exists()` and `file.createNewFile()`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("F:\\FermiPresentCoord.txt");

        file.createNewFile();

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true);

        writer.write("x");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
```

Same error on this ?
Try to change "F:\"  if you dont specify the path it will be put relative to your java excecution. If this is your System Partition you can get permission Problems creating a File.